# Form Wizard: Correct location for wizard_form.html

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I am following the [django tutorial on setting up a Form wizard](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/) but I am having an issue regarding the location for the template to render the form.

I can see in the documentation that this should be located at formtools/wizard/wizard_form.html

My app is called "survey" so I initially thought to put it inside that

```
survey/formtools/wizard/wizard_form.html
```

But I get the error

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /contact/

formtools/wizard/wizard_form.html
```

So then I put it at

```
survey/contact/formtools/wizard/wizard_form.html
```

but no change to the error.

I know I could start changeing the WizzardView but I would like to find out what I am doing wrong.

Below is a screenshot of my project structure. Any help is much apriciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
survey/formtools/wizard/wizard_form.html
```

You should place this in your templates folder in your survey app

Comment: So for future reference the file path that worked for me was "survey/templates/formtools/wizard/wizard_form.html" NOTE: survey is my application.